# Question on mixed-strategy matrix games from Boyd & Vandenberghe

Tags: convex-optimization, game-theory

In *Convex Optimization* by Boyd & Vandenberghe (page 230), they try to prove that in mixed-strategy matrix games, there is no advantage to knowing the opponent's strategy  beforehand.

When the strategy is known beforehand, we have the following situation:

Let $u$ be the vector of Player 1's strategy and $v$ be the vector pf Player 2's strategy (probability vectors), and $\mathbf{P}$ be the payoff matrix.
Expected payoff is $u^\top \mathbf{P}v$. Player 2 will try to maximize the expected Payoff, which results in the optimization problem

\begin{align}
\sup \{u^\top\mathbf{P}v| v \succeq 0, \sum v_i = 1\}
\end{align}

Up to this point, things are very clear.

But then the authors say that above equation is equal to $\max_{i}(\mathbf{P}^\top u)$

I do not understand the last part clearly. It will be equal to the supremum only if we assume that all $v_i$ are equal.  Otherwise how can they drop the $v$ term from the equation ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the supremum is taken over all $v$'s (i.e. over all strategies of Player 2), and that we know $u$ and $P$, what this means is that the strategy which would give player 2 (who wants to maximize the payoff) the highest payoff would be the entry that corresponds to the entry with the highest value in the vector $P^Tu$. To see this, observe that:

$$u^TPv = v^TP^Tu = v^T(P^Tu)$$

Where the first equality follows from the fact that a scalar is its own transpose. If I want to find the vector $v$ that gives me the highest value of $v^T(P^Tu)$, whilst ensuring that $\sum_i v_i = 1$, then I should put set $v_i = 1$ on the entry that corresponds to the maximum entry in $P^Tu$, and zero everywhere else.

Comment: which basically means that $v$ is dynamic. It is not the case that $v$ is a predefined constant vector. am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, I believe that you're right.

Comment: What if the maximal value of $P^Tu$ is not in a unique coordinate? Then you will also have other solutions that are possibly the same. Also what is a little bit confusing. How do you show that $v_i=1$ will lead to the best result? What other conditions do you need for $P^Tu$?

Comment: @MachineLearner You are right, but the value of the sup will stay the same, so it really doesn't matter, since we are only concerned with the value of the sup. To show that setting $v_i = 1$ at the maximum coordinate is a solution which gives the sup, you just need to consider what happens if it isn't (use case analysis - unique vs non unique coords).